# French characters

Tags: input-encodings, french

I am writing my PhD thesis but I have a problem in typing French characters:
like "à" "é" "ç" etc. In the main page I have to use these two packages:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I tried to change them  by using others like

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! I am not sure what your question is, partly because you haven't really asked one, but also partly because you haven't told us exactly what the problem is! Please [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/226703/edit) to specifically tell us exactly what is going wrong. It would also be helpful if you could include a [minimal (non)-working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The encoding specified for inputenc **must** be the same as the encoding of the file. If the file is in Latin-1, then you specify latin1; if the file is in UTF-8, then it’s utf8. Is it the case for you?

Comment: You need to know exactly which encoding is used. Which editor are you using?

Comment: I can't give an example, because I am working in a lot of files that I include them in just one main.tex. So,  the problem  is just, for instance,  in the file of acknowledgments.tex I can write the french characters, but in other file of chapters and while compiling the main.tex I found the problem again  in these chapters.

Comment: you are saving your files in different encodings. Configure your editor to save all files in UTF-8 then use the `[utf8]` option,

Comment: Thaaaannnnnnnnnkkkkkkkkkk you David Carlisle. It is working. MERCI infiniment. Put your comment as an answer plz

Comment: @layth: let me add that if you write in French, you should load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and use a `T1-encoded` font, such as Latin Modern (`lmodern` package).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are saving your files in different encodings.

Configure your editor to save all files in UTF-8 then use the `[utf8]` option,